# Just had 2 firewall path's pop up as letter:number\path\to\exe. Why the weird path?

Tags: windows-10, path, windows-firewall

I just finished upgrading all my hard drives.  Lots of data migration.   Fired up my first game and was prompted for a firewall rule.

Not unexpected as the drive letter the game was on changed, however when I checked the rule, it wasnt S:\path\to\exe as i expected, but E:8\path\to\exe

Then again with another game instead of S: it was E:6...

Anyone able to tip me off on whats going on so i can get proper path's back?

(incredible how rare this seems to be.  I can find nothing on it which convinces me something is broken)

EDIT: I found this. Almost ALL i could find on the web. I dont have the reputation required to comment, much less the proficiency to answer (obviously) so creating a new post was my only alternative as that post is years old with no concrete resolution.  [What does "C:2\" in a windows path string mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/796379/what-does-c2-in-a-windows-path-string-mean)

A pure guess, but due to other proclivities ive stumbled across I came to the realization that my external disks all share a uniqueID that I dont believe can be altered as I posted about here. [How can I solve this DiskID conflict amongst my external disks?](https://superuser.com/questions/1539442/how-can-i-solve-this-diskid-conflict-amongst-my-external-disks)

Beginning to think that maybe these two are related.  Since the firewall path does point to one of those external disks.  A disk which has the same ID as several others.  Perhaps this is windows firewalls only way of substantiating it.  It does seem I can change the paths manually to use the letter instead of the letter:number system its auto assigning and have it still work.

I'd rather understand why its being assigned the way it is as opposed to going back and retroactively changing every one to have the proper letter prefix.